# vid.set(CAP_PROP_FPS,<FPS>) not working in nxp board

Tags: c++, opencv, frame-rate

I wrote a cpp code to capture camera feed show it in live time and store it into a video file.
I've cross compiled the code and ran it on a nxp board.
But when i open the saved video file the playback speed is very high.
So decided to add

`vid.set(CAP_PROP_FPS,24)`

to control the fps of input.
But when i did this it shows an error. the error is as shown below

```
[  114.294445] usb 1-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using cdns-usb3
[ WARN:0] global /usr/src/debug/opencv/4.2.0.imx-r0/git/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (935) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Cannot query video position: status=0, value=-1, duration=-1
[ WARN:0] global /usr/src/debug/opencv/4.2.0.imx-r0/git/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1758) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module v4l2src0 reported: Internal data stream error.
[ WARN:0] global /usr/src/debug/opencv/4.2.0.imx-r0/git/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (515) startPipeline OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
[ WARN:0] global /usr/src/debug/opencv/4.2.0.imx-r0/git/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (966) getProperty OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: no pipeline
[ WARN:0] global /usr/src/debug/opencv/4.2.0.imx-r0/git/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (966) getProperty OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: no pipeline
[ERROR:0] global /usr/src/debug/opencv/4.2.0.imx-r0/git/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (415) open VIDEOIO(GSTREAMER): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.2.0) /usr/src/debug/opencv/4.2.0.imx-r0/git/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:1395: error: (-215:Assertion failed) frameSize.width > 0 && frameSize.height > 0 in function 'open'


[ERROR:0] global /usr/src/debug/opencv/4.2.0.imx-r0/git/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (415) open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.2.0) /usr/src/debug/opencv/4.2.0.imx-r0/git/modules/videoio/src/cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): myvideo.avi in function 'icvExtractPattern'


error reading file
[ WARN:0] global /usr/src/debug/opencv/4.2.0.imx-r0/git/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (480) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
```

this is my code:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    VideoCapture vid(3);
    
    Mat Frame;
    
    if(!vid.isOpened())
    {
        cout<<"Error occured while trying to open camera.\n";
        return -1;
    }
    
    vid.set(CAP_PROP_FPS,24);
    namedWindow("Cam Feed",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    VideoWriter writer;
    writer.open("myvideo.avi",VideoWriter::fourcc('M','J','P','G'),24.0,Size(cap.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), cap.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)));
    while(1)
    {
        
        if(!vid.read(frame))
        {
            cout<<"error reading file\n";
            break;
        }
        
        imshow("Cam Feed",frame);
        
        writer.write(frame);
        
        if(waitKey(30)==113)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    vid.release();
    writer.release();
    destroyAllWindows();
    return 0;
}
```

it works without the
`vid.set(CAP_PROP_FPS,24)`

but i need the code to work with it else the playback speed will be high